# Is there way to Integrate Jupyter note book to my web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, jupyter-notebook, code-editor

I want my own code editor executes the codes via jupyter notebook and has to display the results in my web application UI

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to embed the entire page in `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8888" />
```

One thing that should be noted is that Jupyter notebook by default only allows the page from the same origin to embed it by setting [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) in the header:

```
'headers': {
    'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self'"
}
```

In order to embed it in your own app, you need to overwrite the settings in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to allow any pages to embed it：

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors *"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any different version how to do it? Avoiding the use of `iframes`?